# Get 401 response body in spring web flux security

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

Before I started using spring cloud gateway I was using zuul and it gave a 401 response as below

```
{
    "timestamp": 1500622875056,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Bad credentials",
    "path": "/SPPA/ExecuteSPPAJob"
}
```

But Spring cloud gateway gives only a 401 status but no body. How do I add a similar response body as above with spring web flux security.